# Installing Biopython Error

Tags: biopython

I installed and unzipped the bipython-1.63 package. From my terminal (I'm running OS X 10.8), I typed (in the correct directory):

```
python setup.py build
```

And it returns this error - "`could not create 'build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7': Permission denied`"

My account is the only one on this computer and I do have root access. I even followed the instructions in the installation guide for `biopython` and that didn't work either.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

try: `sudo python setup.py build`

Comment: Agreed. `sudo` gives the installer root user privileges.

Comment: are warnings bad? the above code ran fine.

/Users/xxx/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_deprecated_api.h:11:2: warning: 
      "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by #defining NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API
      NPY_1_7_API_VERSION" [-W#warnings]
#warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by #defining...
 ^
1 warning generated.
/usr/bin/clang -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -L/Users/michaelmostachetti/anaconda/lib -arch x86_64 -arch x86_64 build/temp.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/Bio/motifs/_pwm.o -o build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/Bio/motifs/_pwm.so

Comment: everything seems to be alright. i ran the "python setup.py test" and I only ran into problems with extensions that don't already come with the package. 

Thanks for the help!